# How to type a custom pilet api?

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend, piral

We are using the microfrontend framework piral. For our pilets we want to provide a custom api. Following the tutorials we came up with code like this

```
export interface MyApi {
  example(): void;
}

export function createMyApi(): Extend<MyApi> {
  return context => {
    return (api, target) => {
      return {
        example() {
          alert(`Hello from ${target.name}!`);
        }
      };
    };
  };
}
```

While this seems to be working functionally we could not get this to work with typescript. What are we doing wrong? How can we provide the typings in our pilets too?

Comment: what are `context` and `api` supposed to be used for? What is `Extend<T>`? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be missing the proper declaration merging.

```
import { PiletApi } 'piral-core';

declare module 'piral-core/lib/types/custom' {
  interface PiletCustomApi extends MyApi {}
}
```

So all in all:

```
import { PiletApi } 'piral-core';

export interface MyApi {
  example(): void;
}

declare module 'piral-core/lib/types/custom' {
  interface PiletCustomApi extends MyApi {}
}

export function createMyApi(): Extend<MyApi> {
  return context => {
    return (api, target) => {
      return {
        example() {
          alert(`Hello from ${target.name}!`);
        }
      };
    };
  };
}
```

Hope that helps!